# OpenGL beam spotlight

Tags: opengl, glsl

After reading up on OpenGL and GLSL I was wondering if there were examples out there to make something like this 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtoBj.png
I am particular interesting in the beam and intensity of light (god ray ?) .
Does anybody have a good start point ?

Answer (score -1):

OpenGL just draws points, lines and triangles to the screen. It doesn't maintain a scene and the "lights" of OpenGL are actually just a position, direction and color used in the drawing calculations of points, lines or triangles.

That being said, it's actually possible to implement an effect like yours using a fragment shader, that implements a variant of the shadow mapping method. The difference would be, that instead of determining if a surface element of a primitive (point, line or triangle) lies in the shadow or not, you'd cast rays into a volume and for every sampling position along the ray test if that volume element (voxel) lies in the shadow or not and if it's illuminated add to the ray accumulator.